Help identify episode of 60s SciFi show future dystopia where man can't get his food ration for the month
I'm looking for a B/W 60s(?) 30-min episode SciFi show set in a dystopian future; people must wear gas masks to venture out-of-doors.  For some reason the main character has failed to receive his monthly food ration card/stamps and spends much time trying to convince the bureaucracy of this fact.  Last scene is the first day of the next month where we see the same man with the new month's ration card, but now minus an arm.

It's the 1971 TV movie, And Then They Forgot God:

Prolific television writer Sy Salkowitz wrote and directed this outré dramatic telefilm set in a dystopian future. With a grim plot twist that rivals the darkest of Twilight Zone episodes, this humanistic parable centers on an average couple (Joseph Campanella and Beverly Garland) as they face starvation due to a Kafkaesque bureaucracy. Also features Adam West as a policy-obsessed prosecutor. Presented by writer Paul Cullum and Mark Quigley (UCLA Film & Television Archive). Source: UCLA Film & Television Archive.

As described on another site:

But our favorite was a vaguely Twilight Zone–like parable where a bureaucratic snafu prevents Joseph Campanella from receiving his family’s monthly allotment of food vouchers from the state. Thwarted at every turn by endless red tape (including some from a supercilious prosecutor played by Adam West), Campanella is seen in the final shot grimly receiving his next month’s vouchers, only to reveal the arm of his suit jacket now hanging limp, presumably the source of his family’s intervening sustenance. The elegance of such a payoff was like catnip...

